# Share react native components across repos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, react-native

I have three react native projects each with their own repo.

They use very similar components, is there a way I can share these components across repo's, so I don't have to update each repo independently?

Or can I create three different apps, from one repo? with only very slight changes to images and configs for each app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Separated npm package

In my project, I separated my **core parts** with each npm package.

1. Create `npm` package and put your shared components into that.
2. You can test immediately your shared component's function with `npm link` or specify your local package's absolute path with `npm install`.
3. If you want to manage your package more intuitive way, then you can publish your package to `npm` repository with private mode.

### Solution 2: Depend on the environment variable

You can separate your running environment with [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config). With this package, created multiple environments `.env` or `.env.production` you can separate your runtime variables with `ENVFILE=.env npm start` or `ENVFILE=.env.production npm start`. Then in your javascript code, you can refer your each runtime settings.

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';

const isProduction = Config.environment === 'production';

<Image source={isProduction ? require(..production_image) : require(..development_image)} />
```

---

How to show your slight difference in your app depends on you. like `Platform.os === 'ios'`

Comment: It seems like the link to the Medium article is broken.

Comment: @Gh05d Yes. But I can't find the previous article. So I edited it for removing that.

Answer (score 0):

Refere this: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

You can create different builds : Production, staging, testing.

You can set multiple environment and generate build.